# Iterative Greens function calculation

Tags: greens-functions, self-energy, mean-field-theory

I have a Hamiltonian which has an interactive and non-interactive parts.

$H = H_0 + H_I$

$H_I$ comes from the non-local electron-electron interaction and must be calculated self-consistently.

I start with calculating the non-interacting Greens function which is :

1. $G_0(E, k) = [EI - H_0]^{-1}$

Then I calculate the interacting Greens function with an initial guess for its corresponding self energy.

2. $G(E, k) = [EI - H_0 - \Sigma_I(k)]^{-1}$

$\Sigma_I$ is a Fock like term and its only a function of momentum (k).

The new Greens function is (Dyson equation):

3. $G_{new} = G0 + G0*\Sigma_I*G $

Now my question is how to update the $\Sigma_I(k)$

If I use the equation below and iterate between eq.4 and eq.3, I', not actually updating the $\Sigma (k)$.

4. $\Sigma_I(k)$ = $1/G_0(E, k)$ - $1/G_{new}(E,k)$

So how should I update my self-energy after each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to do a self-consistent Hartree-Fock calculation. Then $\Sigma_I(E,k)$ would be some function of your $G(E, k)$ (as per your diagrammatics). With eq 3 or 4 - they're the same - you can obtain $G_{\text{new}}(E, k)$. Then you repeat the same game with $G_{\text{new}}(E, k)$ until it stops changing a lot after 1 iteration (you can decide this depending on what level of accuracy you're looking for).

You might want to do some obvious checks at the end, eg. spectral function should be positive, check what happens upon increasing discretization etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still don't understand how to update $\Sigma_I(E, k)$ from the $G_{new}(E, k)$. If I want to return to eq.3 I have to put a new $\Sigma_I$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user3687267 You'd start with some trial $G(E,k)$. Then get $\Sigma_I(E, k)$ as a function of $G(E,k)$ using the Feynman diagrams you are using to approximate the self-energy. Then you update $G(E,k)$ to $G_{\text{new}}(E,k)$ and so on & so forth.